# How can I use structured bindings to set an array's values?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm new to C++17 and I ran into a problem when I tried to use structure binding to set values to a couple of array cells. But the regular syntax doesn't work here; it gets confused with the array's brackets.

How can I solve it? Is it even possible?

Example:

```
std::pair<int, int> makePair() {
    return { 10, 20 };
}

int main() {
    int arr[20];

    // error here
    auto [arr[0], arr[1]] = makePair();
}
```

Comment: Try something simpler. If you have `int a,b;` instead of the array, can you bind into `a` and `b`? Can you bind into any pre-existing variables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is the wrong tool for the job. Structured bindings always introduce *new* names; they don't accept arbitrary expressions for lvalues.

But you can do what you want even in C++11. There's [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), for this exact purpose:

```
std::tie(arr[0], arr[1]) = makePair();
```

Give it a bunch of lvalues for arguments, and it will produce a tuple of references to them. `std::tuple` interacts with `std::pair` (considered as two-tuple), and the member-wise assignment modifies the array elements you named.